# ASP.NET - Add/Remove TableRow dynamically in Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a **System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table** with one ROW with five cells with five server controls. I want when click on "Add new row" to create a new ROW **and** how to set a name on first row cells ?

How to do this? Please give me similar tutorials.

**This is my UI:**
[image]

**This is my code:**

```
public class HelloWorldWeb : WebPart
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        //table Cells Controls
        TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
        txt1.Height = 19;
        TextBox txt2 = new TextBox();
        txt2.Height = 19;
        TextBox txt3 = new TextBox();
        txt3.Height = 19;
        DateTimeControl dt1 = new DateTimeControl();
        dt1.DateOnly = true;
        DateTimeControl dt2 = new DateTimeControl();
        dt2.DateOnly = true;
        Button btnAdd = new Button();
        btnAdd.Text = "Create New Row";
        btnAdd.Click += new EventHandler(btnAdd_Click);


        //Declaration one Row and Five Cells(with controls)
        Table myTbl = new Table();
        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();

        TableCell tCellOne = new TableCell();
        tCellOne.Controls.Add(txt1);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellOne);

        TableCell tCellTwo = new TableCell();
        tCellTwo.Controls.Add(dt1);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellTwo);

        TableCell tCellThree = new TableCell();
        tCellThree.Controls.Add(dt2);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellThree);

        TableCell tCellFour = new TableCell();
        tCellFour.Controls.Add(txt2);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellFour);

        TableCell tCellFive = new TableCell();
        tCellFive.Controls.Add(txt3);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellFive);

        myTbl.Rows.Add(tRow);

        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table class='ms-formbody' vAlign='top' >"));

        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td width='100' class='ms-formlabel' noWrap='nowrap' vAlign='top'>"));
        this.Controls.Add(myTbl);
        this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));

        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</table>"));

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

**The result must be :**

[image]

Comment: Make a static counter (this is where the ViewState is okay to use), and have your control creation code loop as often as that counter indicates. The "Add" button increases the counter.

Comment: Your button click doesn't do anything, from what I can tell. You add an "EventHandler" within the CreateChildControls, but that is unnecessary. You only have one button on the page. Use the "btnAdd_Click" event and call the "CreateChildControls" function.

Comment: I guess you could store rows in a `List<>`, add a new item to the list on each click and then just render the rows inside that list.

Comment: Please, show me yours solution in my code... with answer..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what type of project you are working in but using a simple Web Form I can achieve this:

Test.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Stackoverflow.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
                <tbody>
                    <asp:Literal ID="litTest" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Create New Row" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public partial class Test : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                AddRow();
        }

        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddRow();
        }

        private void AddRow()
        {
            litTest.Text += "<tr><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"height: 19px;\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"height: 19px;\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"height: 19px;\"></td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My solution is ClassLibrary.. The code must be only on ".cs".

Answer (score 1):

I like ryantpayton's method, but here's your code revised:

```
public class HelloWorldWeb : WebPart
{
    public HelloWorldWeb()
    {
        CreateTable();
    }
    private void CreateTable()
    {
        //table Cells Controls
        TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
        txt1.Height = 19;
        TextBox txt2 = new TextBox();
        txt2.Height = 19;
        TextBox txt3 = new TextBox();
        txt3.Height = 19;
        DateTimeControl dt1 = new DateTimeControl();
        dt1.DateOnly = true;
        DateTimeControl dt2 = new DateTimeControl();
        dt2.DateOnly = true;
        Button btnAdd = new Button();
        btnAdd.Text = "Create New Row";
        btnAdd.Click += new EventHandler(btnAdd_Click);


        //Declaration one Row and Five Cells(with controls)
        Table myTbl = new Table();
        myTbl.ID = "tblUsers";
        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();

        TableCell tCellOne = new TableCell();
        tCellOne.Controls.Add(txt1);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellOne);

        TableCell tCellTwo = new TableCell();
        tCellTwo.Controls.Add(dt1);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellTwo);

        TableCell tCellThree = new TableCell();
        tCellThree.Controls.Add(dt2);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellThree);

        TableCell tCellFour = new TableCell();
        tCellFour.Controls.Add(txt2);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellFour);

        TableCell tCellFive = new TableCell();
        tCellFive.Controls.Add(txt3);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellFive);

        myTbl.Rows.Add(tRow);

        this.Controls.Add(myTbl);
        this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);

    }

    private void AddNewRow()
    {
        Table tbl = (Table)this.FindControl("tblUsers");

        //table Cells Controls
        TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
        txt1.Height = 19;
        TextBox txt2 = new TextBox();
        txt2.Height = 19;
        TextBox txt3 = new TextBox();
        txt3.Height = 19;
        DateTimeControl dt1 = new DateTimeControl();
        dt1.DateOnly = true;
        DateTimeControl dt2 = new DateTimeControl();
        dt2.DateOnly = true;

        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();

        TableCell tCellOne = new TableCell();
        tCellOne.Controls.Add(txt1);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellOne);

        TableCell tCellTwo = new TableCell();
        tCellTwo.Controls.Add(dt1);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellTwo);

        TableCell tCellThree = new TableCell();
        tCellThree.Controls.Add(dt2);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellThree);

        TableCell tCellFour = new TableCell();
        tCellFour.Controls.Add(txt2);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellFour);

        TableCell tCellFive = new TableCell();
        tCellFive.Controls.Add(txt3);
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellFive);

        tbl.Rows.Add(tRow);
    }

    void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRow();
    }
}
```

Comment: You left out the add button so I added back in. Also could this be simplified further by just calling CreateChildControls() on btnAdd.Click?

Comment: I will keep the data in the table to another, it will possible with this solution? And how to remove rows  ?

Comment: This is not working  CreateChildControls(); in btnAdd_Click event method.. :{

Comment: I'll be honest -- I haven't done much with just class libraries like this. I would shift the creation of rows to a separate function and then call that function however many times you need AND when the button is clicked.Your code is essentially recreating the table when the button is clicked, so no new rows are added -- it just recreates the initial table.I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've added some code including a new function to add a row. I have no idea if it will even work, but hopefully it will guide you towards a solution.